# Thinkpad X201 Fan doesnt work if Intel AMT is disabled

Tags: cooling, intel-amt

http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/X201-Fan-Error-when-ME-AMT-turned-off/td-p/2045078

> I deem Intel AMT a huge security risk
>
> So entered the config of it and set it to disabled.
>
> Now having done this, the laptop reboots and works as usual EXCEPT the fan does not work >and the device gets really hot.
>
> Then I wanted to check in BIOS config for any Fan settings to see, when I enter >"Configuration" submenu the biosmenu freezes until the laptop is powered off manually.
>
> I tested it a few times, tested other settings that seemed to be able to have an impact >on that situation to no avail.
>
> As soon as I turned ME/AMT back on the fan works again and the config menu in bios does >not freeze.
>
> It has the latest bios and ME Firmware from the downloads page.
>
> How can I disable ME without having the thing toast itself to death?

Does anyone of you have an idea how to fix this?

Do you know how to make AMT inaccessible if I cant turn it off?

This laptop has version 6 of AMT (latest on newer boards is 9 or 10), do you know if I can upgrade that to a newer version without needing to convince the vendor to include it in a biosupdate?

Comment: You have verified your running the current revision of the firmware

Comment: The reason you are getting so many accounts is because you are creating "guest" accounts which are only remembered via the cookies in your browser. Clearing the cookies or moving to another computer will then loose access to the account that asked the question. You should create a full account by registering a username and password or logging in with one of the OpenID providers which will mean you can use the account across any machine with only one login. If you need to merge accounts then, after you have created a full account, go to http://superuser.com/contact and select to merge accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Intel systems is constructed to use Intel ME by default. Some Intel ME module can control fan or do other ACPI-things.
Intel AMT is one of Intel ME modules too. If you set Intel ME to Enabled, but don`t init/setup/configure (Provisioning) Intel AMT - it do not work.